# How can I show Label output only from Transformers Pipeline - Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers

[Picture of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4rVX.png)

From the picture, I've given the model a few sentences to analyse. The result from the analysis, I've added a new column to the dataframe called "sentiment".

As you can see, it gives the results in a list format with labels and scores.

What i'm trying to do is only add the Label result. i.e: "POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE", etc.. Is there a way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use another `apply()` to run function which will get only needed value.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: you didn't show minial working code so I have no idea what you have in `sentiment_pipeline` - maybe you could add to this pipe  another function which could clear result. With current code on image I can only suggest to run another `apply()` to clear data.. Or maybe `.str[0].str["label"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how works your `pipe` but you have `list` with `dict` and `pandas` has `.str` to work with string but `.str[index]` works also with `list` or `dict`.

```
df['Sentiment'] = df['Sentiment'].str[0].str['label']
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Sentiment': [
      [{'label':'Negative', 'score': 0.1}],
      [{'label':'Positive', 'score': 0.9}],
   ]      
}) 

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

df['Sentiment'] = df['Sentiment'].str[0].str['label']

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

                               Sentiment
0  [{'label': 'Negative', 'score': 0.1}]
1  [{'label': 'Positive', 'score': 0.9}]

--- after ---

  Sentiment
0  Negative
1  Positive
```